# Trying to filter null values in aliased column - postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

have the following postgresql command:

```
select 
id, page -> 'link' as link, login_time
from 
my_table 
limit 200
```

I would like to add in a where clause to filter out where the link value is not null - so it contains a value.

when i run the following i get an error message:

```
select 
id, page -> 'link' as link, login_time
from 
my_table 
where link is not null
limit 200
```

column link not found

any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a SQL `SELECT` query, [the logical order of operations is not the lexical order](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.12/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/select-statement/select-lexical-vs-logical-order/).

Syntactically, the order is:

1. SELECT
2. FROM
3. WHERE
4. GROUP BY
5. HAVING
6. ORDER BY

But the logical order (ignoring certain edge-cases and things like windowing functions and RDBMS-specific column aliasing) is:

1. FROM
2. WHERE
3. GROUP BY
4. HAVING
5. SELECT
6. ORDER BY

As the `SELECT` happens **after** the `WHERE` (and `HAVING`) you need to put predicates that depend on your *projections* (your `SELECT` clause) into an outer-query.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            id,
            page -> 'link' AS link,
            login_time
        FROM
            my_table
    ) AS iq
WHERE
    iq.link IS NOT NULL
LIMIT
    200
```

Alternatively, you can still do the test in the `WHERE` clause, it just means having to repeat yourself:

```
SELECT
    id,
    page -> 'link' AS link,
    login_time
FROM
    my_table
WHERE
    ( page -> 'link' ) IS NOT NULL
LIMIT
    200
```

(Personal rant: SQL's DRY-violating syntax has been a personal peeve of mine for at least a decade now - I don't understand how it's been 44 years since SQL was standardized in 1975, yet none of the major SQL vendors have made moves to modernize the syntax to be less *asinine*. MySQL did introduce some weird things like special `GROUP BY` behaviour and aliasing, but since version 8 they've decided to become more conformant instead of pushing for changes for the sake of programmer ergonomics - so until a vendor gets serious about modernizing SQL we'll be stuck with a shortsighted and arbitrary aesthetic decision made before computers even had displays capable of displaying more than 40 lines at a time).